# Prototyping input type=file

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I want to add a method for [image preview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) to `input type="file"` prototype. Does its prototype exist? Something like `HTMLInputFileElement`? I found that:

- The [w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) says there is only `HTMLInputElement` object...
- ...but I believe some more special object must exist, since there is [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileList) property specific to `input type="file"`

What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply prototype the `HTMLInputElement` object.  There is no unique object for input elements with different types.  They are all `HTMLInputElement`s with an attribute specifying its type (text/password/file).  Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/wwE6h/.

Comment: You would just add conditional logic in your prototyped function to check if the input element's type is equal to file

Comment: @JanTuroň The element's files property is null unless the type is set to "file".

Comment: @Joe: that is clear - but how is this achieved? There must be some code behind.

Comment: @JanTuroň My guess is that the constructor for this element class will only set FileList to an instance if the type is "file".  This would be handled in the code for the rendering engine.

Comment: @Joe: it makes sense, since `files` is null, not undefined for non-file types